# SQL Sum two rows with the same ID

Tags: sql, sum

I have two tables (orders and transfers) and I would like to sum up only the amount in casese where there are multiple transfers per order.

Thsi is my SQL. The sum works correctly, but SQL still returns two lines - I would just liek to see one line.

SQL:

```
Select
OrderId,
CustomerId,
SUM(Amount) over (partition by O.OrderId) AS Amount
FROM Orders O
LEFT JOIN Transfers T ON O.OrderId = T.OrderId
```

Orders:

| OrderId | CustomerId |
| --- | --- |
| Order_1 | Customer_1 |

Transfers:

| TransferID | Amount | OrderId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Transfer_1 | 5 | Order_1 |
| Transfer_2 | 5 | Order_1 |

This is my expected result:

| OrderId | Customer_Id | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Order_1 | Customer_1 | 10 |

But what I get is:

| OrderId | Customer_Id | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Order_1 | Customer_1 | 10 |
| Order_1 | Customer_1 | 10 |

Comment: Looks like you want a basic `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a basic `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT
    o.OrderId,
    o.CustomerId,
    SUM(t.Amount) AS Amount
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Transfers t ON o.OrderId = t.OrderId
GROUP BY
    o.OrderId,
    o.CustomerId;
```